# count and different results in a query

Tags: mysql

I have this query and result in my database:

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM jos_content 
       WHERE catid=12 AND state=1 
       AND DATE(publish_up) <= NOW() ORDER BY DATE(publish_up) DESC LIMIT 0,5;
```

```
    +----+
    | id |
    +----+
    | 48 |
    | 47 |
    | 46 |
    +----+
    3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I would like to count result:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*), id FROM jos_content 
       WHERE catid=12 AND state=1 
       AND DATE(publish_up) <= NOW() ORDER BY DATE(publish_up) DESC LIMIT 0,5;
```

```
    +----------+----+
    | count(*) | id |
    +----------+----+
    |        3 | 46 |
    +----------+----+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why aren't the 48 and 47 results shown?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a `GROUP BY` clause.  By default, MySQL permits columns in the `SELECT` clause which are not also included in a `GROUP BY` (which is an error in most other RDBMS).  Without the `GROUP BY`, MySQL will return the first of the associated columns, which is often not the correct intended result.

```
SELECT 
  count(*), 
  id
FROM jos_content
WHERE catid=12 AND state=1 AND DATE(publish_up) <= NOW() 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY DATE(publish_up) DESC
LIMIT 0,5;
```

Not requiring all columns in the `GROUP BY` is helpful if you want to return multiple columns in a summary which are always unique, as something like the following, where `name` is unique to `id`, but you MUST group at least one column for an aggregate to act correctly and produce a summary:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  name,
  COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
```

For compatibility with other RDBMS, and to avoid bugs, I recommend *always* including all the `SELECT` columns in the `GROUP BY` explicitly.

#### Update

With better understanding of what you attempted, if you want the total count of all rows beside the id of each row, you can use a subselect like in the `SELECT` list.  This is going to be a bit slow though.

```
SELECT
  id,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_content) AS numitems
FROM jos_content
WHERE catid=12 AND state=1 AND DATE(publish_up) <= NOW() 
ORDER BY DATE(publish_up) DESC
LIMIT 0,5;
```

You can trick this to work a little faster by doing a cartesian join (no `ON` clause) against the count in a subquery, so it shouldn't get executed for each row. Only do this if the subquery will return exactly one row.

```
SELECT
  id
  numitems
FROM 
  jos_content
  /* Join with no ON clause */
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numitems FROM jos_content) subq
WHERE catid=12 AND state=1 AND DATE(publish_up) <= NOW() 
ORDER BY DATE(publish_up) DESC
LIMIT 0,5;
```

Comment: I didn't know that MySQL allowed that, and silently did the "weird thing" - must just be luck that I haven't been bitten by that before. +1 just for that reminder!

Comment: Hello, I have just realized it doesn't work, it shows always 1 in the count(*) value, and I need the 3.

Comment: @user1256477 So you want the total count for all rows beside each id, not the count for that id?

Comment: Yes, I think I should do it in two queries!

Comment: @user1256477 Review what I added above.  Those will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Count is aggregate function, so if you want to include any of the column then that column must be part of group by clause in the query.

Comment: It will return only one record, so not possible to display all value of id column.

Comment: @Michael, yes it's possible with workarounds. I have mentioned the way Group by works in case of count(*) in select statement.